# jqgrid - dynamically enabling grouping

Tags: jqgrid

I was able to implement grouping feature from examples in the jqgrid demo page. But I don't want to enable grouping by default but on the change of a select list I would like to enable the grouping feature. I have tried several options but none of them were successful? Could some one please help me here, may be I am missing something. Here is my code...

```
$("#dynamicGrouping").change(function() { 
    var value = $(this).val(); 
    if(value) { 
        if(value == '') { 
            $('#grid').jqGrid('groupingRemove', true); 
        } else { 
            $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { grouping:true });
            $('#grid').jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', value);
            $('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid');
        } 
    }
});
```

My grid definition:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('#grid').jqGrid({
            .....
            .....
        grouping: false,
        groupingView : { 
                groupField : ['field_name'], 
            groupColumnShow : [true], 
            groupText : ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'], 
            groupCollapse : false, 
            groupOrder: ['asc'], 
            groupDataSorted : true 
            },
        .......
        .......
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like there is an open issue for this on github. Please see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/328). I have recently upgraded to jgrid 4.4.1 version and still have this issue...

Comment: Got the help from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595828/jqgrid-and-dynamic-grouping) but the performance is really poor and jqgrid takes a long time to load grouped data. Any better way to fix this please? Thanks in advance. var GroupOption = new Object();
var groupField = [];
groupField.push(value);
GroupOption.groupField = groupField;
GroupOption.groupText = ['<b> {0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'];
GroupOption.groupDataSorted = true;
GroupOption.groupOrder = ['asc'];
msgGrid.setGridParam({groupingView : GroupOption});
msgGrid.setGridParam({grouping : true});
msgGrid.trigger('reloadGrid');

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I supposed that you made some error in the code. The code which you posted seem me correct, but you don't need to set `grouping:true` and trigger `reloadGrid` additionally because `groupingGroupBy` do this you automatically.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SetGroupingDynamically.htm) demonstrates setting or removing of grouping dynamically.

[image]

So you can use

```js
$("#dynamicGrouping").change(function () {
    var groupingName = $(this).val();
    if (groupingName) {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', groupingName);
    } else {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('groupingRemove');
    }
});
```

or a little more advanced version

```js
$("#dynamicGrouping").change(function () {
    var groupingName = $(this).val();
    if (groupingName) {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', groupingName, {
            groupOrder : ['desc'],
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupCollapse: true
        });
    } else {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('groupingRemove');
    }
});
```

**UPDATED**: Everything works with JSON data too: see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SetGroupingDynamically1.htm).

**UPDATED 2**: I looked in the code one more time and I found out that `gridview` will set to `true` **at the initialization of grid**: see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2159-2165). If you don't have  `gridview: true` and use initially `grouping: false` then you will be not able to change just `grouping: true`. You have to set also other parameters from [the grouping limitations](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#limitations) correctly.

So you have to hold the rules from limitations yourself:

```js
scroll: false,
rownumbers: false,
treeGrid: false,
gridview: true,
```

By the way I recommend **always use `gridview: true`** because of better performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Could you please try your solution for remote data(groupDataSorted : true). I have tried your solution but it did n't work for remote data. The back end query sends the grouping information but jqgrid does n't enable grouping dynamically. Please let me know if you cannot reproduce this issue with remote data. I will try to get you the complete code to reproduce it. Thanks...

Comment: @varaprakash: Try to open `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of the version of jqGrid which you use and search for `groupDataSorted`. I don't find it. The option don't exist in last versions of jqGrid. The last version of jqGrid where I found the option was jqGrid 4.3.3. I used jqGrid 4.4.1 in my demo. So the usage of the option has no sense. The last version uses `sortname` option only. Which version you use?

Comment: I was using jqGrid 4.1.2 and upgraded to 4.4.1 few days back. You were right, this option is not available in 4.4.1 src and I could see it in 4.1.2. How do we implement grouping on remote data now? Could you please verify for remote data and see if you could reproduce my issue? Thanks..

Comment: I removed groupDataSorted: true option but still the same issue :(

Comment: @varaprakash: I see no problem with remote data too: see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SetGroupingDynamically1.htm)

Comment: In your demo, when I change the grouping field in select option, it does not make any back end server call. Looks like you have loadonce: true. Not sure if that could be the issue. Thanks..

Comment: @varaprakash: You are welcome! Sorry, but I can't make more and more demos for you. I can repeat, that I don't see any bug in grouping. If you have demo which don't work you should provide it. For example you can create the demo on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19500/discussion-between-varaprakash-and-oleg)

Comment: I am having a problem.My grouping is not working on a specific column, then if click the refresh button from the tbar then grouping works.This is only for a specific column.I checked for other columns, but are working good.Can you say, why it happens?

Comment: @janina: Sorry, but I have too few information about what you do. Could provide the demo which shows the problem?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I just solved it.All I need to do was using OrderBy in server side data render.