# How do i set the groupField from jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, field

This is my code: `groupField : [group],`, where group is a dynamic parameter. I'm using the grouping method with a dropdown. In the dropdown I have an option:"Default". The Default value represents that there is no grouping. So my question is how to I set groupingField as null ? or something else in order to NOT doing the grouping method. thx

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you are trying to implement dynamic grouping via a dropdownlist. And your default option (No Grouping) is not working. the problem is to represent no value in your `groupField : [group],` .
    The solution is to remove grouping from the grid by using          `$("#grid").jqGrid('groupingRemove',true);`.
    Normally i will use dropdown change function to dynamically pass grouping into my grid. here is a excellent explanation by Oleg. [jqgrid - dynamically enabling grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657053/jqgrid-dynamically-enabling-grouping).  many thanks [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg)